# I want to know if there is a way to find out if element.textContext is active or element.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to know if there is a way to find out if element.textContext is active or element.innerHTML on a DOM element because if you say element.textContext = '', it starts to ignote the innerHTML attriute

Comment: You can know the value by `console.log(element.innerHTML)`. If there is no value then it returns `` nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped. I started coding recently so I needed help for this thing.

Comment: Happy to be helpful and I hope your happy coding journey.